# Web App running on local but after deployment on azure is giving error

Tags: asp.net, excel, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app in which I am reading some data from Microsoft Excel. It is working fine on my desktop but when I am deploying it on Azure it is giving me below error when I visit that page. I am using Microsoft Office Interop Excel as a reference in my app. If someone can help me in this regard?

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Stack Trace:
>
> [COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due
>   to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +119
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +247    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11    Painting.Painting2.imageRetriever() in D:\Work (D)\Generix\Painting
>   Web\Visual Studio\Salman Bhai Fixes\Work
>   7-18-2018\Painting\Painting\Painting2.aspx.cs:24
>   Painting.Painting2.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Work
>   (D)\Generix\Painting Web\Visual Studio\Salman Bhai Fixes\Work
>   7-18-2018\Painting\Painting\Painting2.aspx.cs:17
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +51    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +678

Comment: I believe you've hit the [sandbox COM restrictions](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#access-to-out-of-process-com-servers). Not familiar with Office SDK, but there should be a way to use those components without COM.

Comment: The alternative is deploy to Cloud Services with a Web Role. No sanbox there, you own the instance.

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935980/hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classnotreg-error-my-website-is-on-azure-cloud/50936559#50936559 alternatively you can also use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/host-an-office-add-in-on-microsoft-azure