# Is there a way to register COM class factory in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have deployed my application on azure as webjobs. Application use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll and Offcie.dll to convert the flat file to excel file. I know Azure do not have office on it and it is throwing error

```
"Error Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154. Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))".
```

Is there a to register the COM class in Azure app service?
This issues was there in Azure from 8-10 years,  in this years has microsoft come up with any solution or alternative for this?

I do not want to use other open source/Openxml because I have to re-write the whole application.

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Comment: If you are still unsure, you can [raise a support ticket to confirm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` depends on the server to install Office software.

## As far as I know, azure app services are currently not supported and cannot register COM class.

If you really don't want to use third-party libraries, such as Openxml, you can only choose virtual machine, install office, and use it.

Related post：

[HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG), error, my website is on azure cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935980/hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classnotreg-error-my-website-is-on-azure-cloud/50936559#50936559)